# QML ListView place new list item below last list item

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to create a simple chat bubble layout where the height of each message's rectangle can be variable while the width is fixed. Now we need to place the new message right below the last message present in the listview. Since height is variable, `ListView.spacing` can't be decided between any two elements. So how can I achieve this?

Listview code:

```
    ListView{
    id: listView
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 10
    delegate: ChatMessageItem{}
    model: listModel
    spacing: 10
}
```

ChatMessageItem's code

```
Item{
Rectangle {
color: "#6BB9F0"
height: 50
width: (childrenRect.width < 200? childrenRect.width : 200)
radius: 7
Text {
    id: name
    text: username
}
Text {
    id: message
    text: msg
    anchors.top: name.bottom
    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    Component.onCompleted: {
        if(width > 200)
            width = 200;
        else if(width < 50)
            width = 50;
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: What is listModel?

Comment: @JeffreyvandeGlind ListModel is a derived class of class model. Models are used to bind data with a view.

Comment: Ok, when you insert new messages, are they index `0` or index `count()-1`?

Comment: The latter option @JeffreyvandeGlind

Comment: Ok, than normally ListView should update (if signals are properly implement) and put the last message at the bottom. So where are you having an issue?

Comment: We need to specify 'spacing' property in QML for listviews. Have you used QT before? @JeffreyvandeGlind

Comment: What do you mean by "specify". In your code you hard coded it to 10.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113862/discussion-between-akash-aggarwal-and-jeffrey-van-de-glind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that your `Item` does not has a height. Your `ListView` therefore does not know what height your delegates have. This has nothing to do with your `ListView.spacing`. Try the following change:

```
Item{
    height: rect.height
Rectangle {
    id: rect

color: "#6BB9F0"
height: name.paintedHeight + message.paintedHeight
width: (childrenRect.width < 200 ? childrenRect.width : 200)
radius: 7
Text {
    id: name
    text: username
}
Text {
    id: message
    text: msg
    anchors.top: name.bottom
    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    Component.onCompleted: {
        if(width > 200)
            width = 200;
        else if(width < 50)
            width = 50;
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: The outer `Item` is not even needed here, you could put the `Rectangle` as the root item.